# Login in web page with cookies in Java

Tags: java, cookies, httpclient

I want to download a file from a web page which needs user and pass, but first I have to get the cookies. What I want to do is exactly described in this Python script, but I want to do it using Java.

I have been reading about that, and I have found httpclient library. Is httpclient all I need? Any equivalent library for mechanize and urllib2 in java?

Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import mechanize, urllib2
from urllib import urlopen, urlencode 

user = 'username'
password = 'password'
output_file = 'name.pdf'

web = "https://..."
bills_page = "https://.../bills"
login_web = "https://.../login/"
file = "https://.../file_I_want"

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(web)

data = {
    'user_username': user,
    'user_password': password,
    'idClientehidden': '',
    'answer': ''
}

response1 = urllib2.Request(login_web, urlencode(data))

br.open(response1)
br.open(bills_page)
html_bills = br.response().read()

br.open(file)
pdf_bill = open(output_file, 'w')
pdf_bill.write(br.response().read())
pdf_bill.close()
```

Comment: Is your question all about reading cookies? or are you looking for ways to login on external web and download the files?

Comment: Ways to login on external web and download the file. My question is if I have to use httpclient or if you know something better for my objective.

Answer (score 3):

[**HttpClient**](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) is a good framework for dealing with cookies and accessing authenticated URLs.

Alternatively you can use core Java components such as [**Authenticator**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html), [**URL**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and [**BufferedReader**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) as below:

1. Create a custom Authenticator which will read `userId/Password` from the cookie

   ```
   public class HTTPAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        String username = "user"; //<--read from cookie
        String password = "password"; //<--read from cookie
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
     }
   }
   ```
2. Set your custom authenticator `HTTPAuthenticator` as default Authenticator.

   ```
   Authenticator.setDefault(new HTTPAuthenticator());
   ```
3. Once done, read the files and write in your local drive as below:

   ```
   URL url = new URL("http://secureweb/secure.html");
   BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
   File file = new File("myLocalFile");
   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (file);
   String lineStr;
   while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        bw.write();
   }
   bw.close();
   br.close();
   ```

Hope this helps.